# How do you unwrap a tileable arch?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm having trouble with unwrapping and retopologizing this model here:

[image]

Here is my topology:

[image]

Is there a better way to topologize it? And how should I go about unwrapping this so that I can map a horizontal trim sheet to it and have it look nice? I got kind of close, but there's distortion and it just isn't right. I overlapped the two sides of the mesh into one set of UV as you can see here:

[image]

Any advice is welcome, except if you're going to say it's impossible. I won't accept that as an answer and I will hate you if you say that, and I will specifically try to find a solution just to spite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the other way around: Enable the *Correct Face Attributes* option, then flatten the topology in the 3D view. As Gordon Brinkmann says, for the flattening, you can select the vertices bottom to top and use *Active Element* as pivot point, then *S + axis + 0*:

[image]

[image]

You can also cut with the Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally since 3.0), then delete the left part:

[image]

Comment: For the flattening, why don't you select the vertices bottom to top and use _Active Element_ as pivot point? That way you don't have to move it after flattening...

Comment: sure, I'm going to add that in my answer

Comment: I mean it's not less work or easier, it just helps keeping the position of that top vertex  ;)

Comment: yes I know...  ;)

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I made an arch the normal way and cut it like that like you showed. There's still a bit of distortion, but it's pretty small so I'm not sure that it matters.

Comment: you may be able to fix it if you move the UV vertices a bit

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann + moonboots .. Definitely the cut, not the scale, IMO, for good practice. There are all sorts of reasons you might want to preserve the direction of the radial edges, further down the line.

Comment: @RobinBetts For good practice, yes. I just wanted to say how the scaling could be done better if you use that method (and the cut method wasn't edited into the answer when I commented) 